# Stop Doctrine / Symfony from loading associated entities during foreach? (lazy loading not happening)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm seeing doctrine generating additional queries to load entities that I'm not directly accessing.  I thought that lazy loading meant these associate entities wouldn't get loaded.  Can you help me figure out why the queries are happening and how to stop them?

Here's the entities in question:

```
class Invoice
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InvoiceCard", mappedBy="invoice")
    */
    protected $cards;

    ...
}
class BaseInvoiceCard
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice", inversedBy="cards")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $invoice;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Printing")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="printing_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $printing;

    ...
}
class InvoiceCard extends BaseInvoiceCard{ ... }
class Printing{ ... }
```

This line of code doesn't cause any queries to the InvoiceCards table:

```
$cards = $invoice->getCards();
```

Once I do this:

```
foreach($cards as $card){
    //do nothing in this loop
}
```

I get a "SELECT ... FROM invoicecard", which is expected.

*However*, I'm also getting a "SELECT ... FROM printing" for every $card in $cards.  I never call $card->getPrinting().  This happens even if I do nothing at all inside the loop; just running it causes doctrine to run these queries.

Why this happening and how can I prevent it?

**EDIT:**  This is the code for getCards().

```
/**
 * Get cards
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCards()
{
    return $this->cards;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I've found a workaround to this problem, though it's not going to solve things in the long run.  I fetch the InvoiceCards as an array, rather than having doctrine hydrate them as entities.

```
$query->getArrayResult();
```

In my current situation, this technique is better anyways, since I don't require the overhead of full hydration.

However, the application will be working with InvoiceCards in many places, and the original issue will be still be a problem then.  I feel like either I've misunderstood Doctrine's lazy loading, or it isn't working as expected.

Comment: Can you post your code for getCards()?  It may return more data and entities.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code for getCards()

Comment: Have you tried `EXTRA_LAZY`? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: Yes, adding fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" to $printing has no effect

Comment: I've found a workaround, but am still trying to figure out the original issue.  See EDIT 2.

Comment: you could create a repository for the InvoiceCard and create an explicite query with the entity you want selected.  Is that the workaround you used?

Comment: Yes, that's my workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entities were getting eagerly loaded because Printing is a parent class whose children use single table inheritance.

If I change $printing to point to leaf entity, lazy loading works as desired.

From the Doctrine docs, **[7.2.2. Performance impact](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact)**

> There is a general performance consideration with Single Table Inheritance: If the target-entity of a many-to-one or one-to-one association is an STI entity, it is preferable for performance reasons that it be a leaf entity in the inheritance hierarchy, (ie. have no subclasses). Otherwise Doctrine **CANNOT** create proxy instances of this entity and will **ALWAYS** load the entity eagerly.

Comment: I'm not allowed to add comments yet, but the link is broken and [here is the current working one](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact)

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact