# Symfony serialization with groups and relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony's serializer to return a JSON response. I use groups to only return information that is relevant:

```
return new JsonResponse($this->serializer->serialize($userRepository->getActiveUser(), 'json', ['groups' => ['contact-information']]));
```

My `User` class has additional relationships I am not interested in for the above request, like `paymentProfile`. This property has a different group:

```
class User {
...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=PaymentProfile::class)
     * @Groups({"payment-information"})
     */    
    protected $paymentProfile;  

}
```

The JSON returned does NOT include the `paymentProfile` property for `User`s (as expected), yet looking at the Symfony Profiler, I see that the request required 100s of individual paymentProfile queries (one for each users returned):

[image]

Repository:

```
    public function getActiveUsers()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.active= :active')
            ->setParameter('active', true)
            ->getQuery()->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

Don't serialization groups prevent unnecessarily fetching data? If yes, what am I doing wrong? If not, how can I get rid of the extra queries?

EDIT:

`Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES` is also not fixing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: @IwanWijaya - ya, that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

> There is a general performance consideration with Single Table Inheritance: If the target-entity of a many-to-one or one-to-one
> association is an STI entity, it is preferable for performance reasons that it
> be a leaf entity in the inheritance hierarchy, (ie. have no subclasses).
> Otherwise Doctrine CANNOT create proxy instances of this entity and will ALWAYS load the entity eagerly. (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact)

H/T https://stackoverflow.com/a/25754165/1550361