# Leaking memory while traversing an object graph

Tags: php, memory, doctrine-orm

Does traversing the object graph in doctrine scale well?

Consider this graphlike entity (guaranteed acyclic):

```
/**
  * @ORM\Entity()
  */
class Node {
    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Node")
     */
    public $child1;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Node")
     */
    public $child2;
    // ...
}
```

I am traversing an object graph in an iterative fashion like so

```
$root = $this->em->find(Node::class, '1');
$stack = new Ds\Stack();
$stack->push($root->getId());
while(!$stack->isEmpty()) {
    $node = $em->find(Node::class, $stack->pop());
    work_on($node);
    if($node->child1) $stack->push($node->child1->getId());
    if($node->child2) $stack->push($node->child2->getId());
    $this->em->clear();
    gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

In practice, my stack size is up to 70.000, I am traversing graphs of size 1.000.000 nodes.

So this is **depth-first-search**. I'd expect the memory consumption to stay kind of constant, but it rises and rises, I am seeing 8 GB and more.
I am pretty sure to not keep any reference to the processed nodes.

If I leave the UoW-clearing out and perform a prefetch `$em->getRepository(Node:class)->findAll()` in the beginning, I get 13 GB memory and that's it then. So to me it seems the clearing does not help really, somehow freeing the processed objects does fail.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, partly here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25754165/5330805.
and by realizing this situation:

[image]

Say I visited root, then A, then B (depth first search).

When working on root, I added A, D,E,F and G to the stack.
G will be processed very late but has already a reference to A.
So when I finish A, there is in fact still a reference to A (in G), so it will stay in memory.

This would not be an issue if doctrine just loaded a Proxy in G pointing to A, but:

In fact my entity is an inheritance hierarchy (I have eg. `BigNode extends Node` and `SmallNode extends Node`), and my associtations are defined to the base class `Node`.

According to the [doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#performance-impact), it is impossible to just instantiate an uninitialized Proxy in this case, the children all must be fetched.

Damn.